# What is the proper Linux suspend resume kernel reentry point when the processor is powered down and back up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on expanding the suspend and resume capability for Linux running on a Xilinx Zynq Soc that has dual ARM A9s using the Xilinx 2014.4 PetaLinux distribution that uses the 3.17 kernel.

The distribution currently supports suspend and resume without removing power to the processors. I am working on expanding the support to include removing power to the processors while the DDR memory is in self refresh mode, then performing a warm boot and having the first stage boot loader (FSBL) hand control back to the Linux kernel in the correct spot to continue with the resume process.

I am looking for what routine to have the first stage boot loader call. I think it might be cpu_resume in arch/arm/kernel/sleep.S, but I am not sure and would like to verify that it is the correct routine to be calling.

I am jumping to this from the FSBL after a suspend and warm boot, and single stepping through the code in a debugger. It gets past the point of turning the MMU back on, but the debugger looses connection near the end of that routine.

In an effort to see if this is the correct entry point, I have modified pm.c in arch/arm/mach-zynq.c to call soft_restart(virt_to_phys(cpu_resume)) just after the resume has happened in the case where the processors are not powered off, but are woken back up with an interrupt.  The soft_restart routine turns off the MMUs and clears the caches, and I am using it to get the processors into a similar state as to what they would be in if they had been power cycled. This test mostly works, and gets much further than calling cpu_resume from the FSBL. The cpu_resume routine expects to be called with cache and MMU off.

I have read the Documentation/power/devices.txt file, and anything else I could find.

I have already done a version of this that uses the no OS flow to put the DDR into self refresh and power cycle the processors, and tested it on hardware. That flow does not use virtual memory.

Thank you in advance,

John

Comment: This is a fascinating project, but you may have better luck asking on the Linux kernel mailing list.

Comment: As you mentiond "It gets past the point of turning the MMU back on, but the debugger looses connection near the end of that routine." Did you mean functions `cpu_resume_mmu`?